why is my code not giving me min avg and gives me 0.00
my code is not giving me min avg but just gives me 0.00 as answer i have tried using gpt but to no avail has it been fruitful
class Solution 
{
    public double minimumAverage(int[] nums) 
    {
        double[] averages = new double [nums.length];
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        int startpos = 0;
        int endpos = nums.length-1;
        while (startpos<=endpos) 
        {
            int[] subarray = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums,startpos,endpos + 1);
            int min = Arrays.stream(subarray).min().getAsInt();
            int max = Arrays.stream(subarray).max().getAsInt();
            double average = (double) (min+max)/2.0;
            averages[startpos] = average;
            startpos++;
            endpos--;
        }
        double avgMin = Arrays.stream(averages).min().getAsDouble();
        return avgMin;
    }
}

Note : The problem statement is LeetCode 3194;
my initial approach was basically sorting the array and then modifying start and end position ans respectively find avg min

((double) min + max)/2.0

You have created averages with same size as nums but with startpos++; endpos--; not all of its elements are reassigned values. So for the remaining elements, by default the values are set to 0.
Therefore, min() of averages always returns 0.
Use half the num size
double[] averages = new double [nums.length/2];

Since you have sorted the array, for min and max, simply use the index
int min = num[startpos];
int max = num[endpos];

There are still few improvements that can be made, I'll leave that for you.

thank you as might know from the above code i am a learner and what i really want to work on is writing cleancode like you suggested writing int min = nums[startpos] now this is something that i should been able to think but i couldnt so yeah any tips regarding this....... thanks for answering tho!

@KrishVij Code in ide like Eclipse or IntelliJ and use the debugger, that'll help you a lot.
